# How to pass location state and URL params using React-Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When I click on the link in the `HoverBooks` Component to get to a new page where I can render the `book` location state in `Book` component, but when I press on it nothing happens. I think the error is in `Route`:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/book:/book.Key">
            <Book />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/signin">
            <Signin />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Header />
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App

import React from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
const Book = () => {
  const {
    state: { book },
  } = useLocation()
  console.log({ book })
  return (
    <div key={book.key}>
      <h1>{book.bookName}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Book

const HoverBooks = ({ ...book }) => {
  const [inHoverBooks, setInHoverBooks] = React.useState(false)
  return (
    <>
      <Link
        to={{
          pathName: `/book/${book.key}`,
          state: {
            book,
          },
        }}
      >
        <img
          onMouseLeave={() => setInHoverBooks(false)}
          onMouseEnter={() => setInHoverBooks(true)}
          src={book.image}
          key={book.key}
        />
      </Link>
      {inHoverBooks && (
        <div className="hover__containter">
          <h3>{book.bookName}</h3>
          <h2>{book.by}</h2>
          <h2>{book.Narreted}</h2>
          <h2>{book.length}</h2>
          <h2>{book.rating}</h2>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
export default HoverBooks
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is the correct form, e.g. `/:someName`, to define a route with **URL params**:

```
<Route path="/book/:bookKey">
  <Book />
</Route>
```

And here is the right syntax to make a `Link` for the above route:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/book/SOME_BOOK_KEY`, // replace SOME_BOOK_KEY with some value
    state: {
      book,  // e.g. const book = { key: 'js', bookName: 'Learn JavaScript'}
    },
  }}
>
  <img src="some_src" alt="something" />
</Link>
```

And you [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) and [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) react-hooks to access the "URL params" and "location state" in a component:

```
const Book = () => {
  const {
    state: { book },
  } = useLocation()
  const { bookKey } = useParams();

  console.log(book, bookKey) 
  // prints "book" object (from location state) and "bookKey" (from URL params)

  return (
    <div key={book.key}>
      <h1>{book.bookName}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I would suggest you to add [typescript](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) to your ReactJS app. It helps you find errors early by doing "static Type-checking".

Comment: Still the same, I can't even get the book object displayed in the console

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-https-02bhm?file=/src/App.js I hope it works

Comment: or this one https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-glitter-2yc7s?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I think that TypeScript is about "using", not "learning". You "use" TS and you learn "JS". An example: `const i = 10` is JS, but `const i: number = 10` is TS. I would suggest that keep learning JS and start using TS. Check https://www.typescriptlang.org/ and https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/ You can start using it after maximum 1 day of learning. So, it is not hard.

Comment: Thank you kind Sir

Answer (score 0):

With react router you need to pass the component you want to render to the `Route` like this

```
const ComponentA = (props) => {...}

<Route path="/component-a" component={ComponentA} />
```

And here is how to link to component a

```
<Link to="/component-a" >Go to component A</Link>
```

Comment: @mura1 What part of it?